# UV-Map too small?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

i just finished a 3D model which is very high poly in some parts. Now i wanted to start texturing it in the texture paint menu. But apparently the brush size is too big. I set it to the smallest value (1px) but thats still a lot bigger than the mesh on the UV map. Meaning i cant paint very precise at the high poly parts because the brush covers a very large part of the mesh.

In my example: I can only paint like the whole claw of my creature with one color. (Take a look at the picture to understand what im talking about). [image: This one]

Now i was thinking if you could somehow make the UV Map bigger to spread the faces further (meaning having more space to distribute). Is that possible?
Or should I try to get rid of some polygons? If yes whats the best way to do that? I already tried the decimate modifier but it doesnt really do anything.

Thanks for the help in advance, Thomas

Comment: You are supposed to create an other UVMap becaouse this is too uneven. Try to mark seams before Unwrap. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/seams.html

Comment: Looks like you could really use a retopo step first so that you have a better topology to unwrap before painting.

Comment: yeah that would be a lot smarter, thanks ;)